# How do I run through the DKIM authentication?

Tags: email-spoofing, dkim

I am currently reading on DKIM authentication for email and I would like to manually try to run through it (to facilitate my understanding of DKIM), but I would like to verify if it is possible to do so.

My intended steps to run through this:

- Obtaining DKIM record from Gmail using "nslookup -type=TXT
  selector.google.com" (Selector is based on field "s=" and domain is
  based on field "d=")
- Take an email from Gmail and based on the DKIM header, extract the
  headers to be encrypted "Based on field "h=""
- Take the "b=" header to obtain the hash of the headers encoded in
  base64
- Based on the public key obtain from the DKIM record (Step 1), encrypt
  the headers of the email stated in "h="
- Encode the output into base64 and compare with the value of "b="

I would like to ask for advice if these steps are possible as I am unable to perform the following task:

- Decoding the value in the field "b=" (Base64 decoders seem to give me
  gibberish output after decoding)
- Encrypting the headers with the public key from step 1, is there any
  way (website) to encrypt the email headers with a public key?

Comment: You basically ask for tools or websites which do base64 and encryption for you - which isn't really about information security but about finding tools. And the "gibberish" you see from the base64 decoders is likely because the output is binary - as expected. Similar the output from encryption will be binary.

Comment: Also, 'Encrypting the headers with the public key from step 1' is incorrect.  DKIM authentication involves verifying a digital signature using the signer's public key, not encrypting something using the signer's public key.  The steps can be done using command line tools like openssl, but it's complicated.  You're better off using a tool such as opendkim (http://www.opendkim.org/).